# Signing a JNLP with $$context not working in java 7.45

Tags: java, jnlp

I have a JNLP that has codebase="$$context"

I sign the JNLP by placing it in the JAR as JNLP-INF/APPLICATION.JNLP prior to signing the JAR.

When launching the app I get "the field codebase has an invalid value in the signed launch file: $$context".

The $$context in the main JNLP that gets launched in the browser gets replaced ok and is valid.  The jnlp in the signed JAR file does not get replaced obviously and is thus invalid.  How do I reconcile this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The APPLICATION.JNLP should not contain codebase="$$context". 
It must contain the the exact codebase. (see [jnlp specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/signedJNLP.html#signedJnlp))

However, there are scenario's that the codebase is dynamic. In that case, you should use APPLICATION_TEMPLATE.JNLP and put an '*' in the codebase attribute.

The $$context is used by a JNLPDownloadServlet that generates a jnlp at runtime, but for signed JNLP's this is quite problematic, since this generated jnlp must be **exactly** the same as the one in the signed jar (apart from the '*').

A solution to this, is having a servlet that extracts the APPLICATION_TEMPLATE.JNLP from the signed jar, replaces the '*'by the correct codebase, and returns it to the browser.